# Object Literal in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, object-literal

I have an extension that needs to pop up a window and then close it.

```
 var my_extension = {
    window: null,
    popup: function(){
       my_extension.window = window.open(...)
    },
    close: function(){
       my_extension.window.close()
    }
 }
```

The popup calls the close function.  However, after returning from the open, the my_extension.window is null.  I check to make sure it is set in popup.  Is another instance of my_extension created when the popup returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my_extension is defined in the main browser window, not in the popup. To close the popup from the popup itself, just use window.close

edit: ok, so I guess `my_extension.close` actually looks something like:

```
function() {
  // check input from popup window
  if (everythingIsGood) {
    my_extension.window.close()
  }
}
```

In that case, I would recommend you do that validation in the popup itself. I know, you don't want to put a lot of code in the popup window. And I agree. But you can pass in whatever information is necessary to do the validation (including passing a validation *function* -- remember that functions are objects too, because JavaScript is cool like that!) when you open the popup. Look for the discussion of `window.arguments` on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.openDialog

Comment: I only want to close the popup if the data entered has been validated by the Firefox extension.  That is why I want to be able to close the popup from the Firefox extension.